# Outgoing messages are being dropped for client x

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have a client (ESP32) running umqtt.simple, and a broker (Pi) running Paho.MQTT. The Broker sends messages to the client. The client simply subscribes - and calls some functions as part of `client.call_back()`.

I am am using client.ping() to keep the client connection alive.

The client works, but I notice that after some time the client stops receiving messages. Looking at `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` on the broker I see the message 'Outgoing messages are being dropped for client [CLIENT NAME]`.

There is no disconnect shown.

I am trying to work out why outgoing messages are being dropped. The only question I can see describing this is here: [Mosquitto: Outgoing messages are being dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130641/mosquitto-outgoing-messages-are-being-dropped). They suggest the solution is to set `max_queued_messages 0` in `mosquitto.conf`. The explanation for this is that this parameter controls the 'maximum number of QoS 1 or 2 messages to hold in the queue (per client)'.

The issue is I am publishing my messages from the broker with the default `qos = 0`, which is 'fire and forget'. Nothing should be being held.

Here is a simplified account of my code on the broker - which is dropping messages for the client.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
BROKER = [broker_ip]
uname = [uname]
pwd = [password]

def on_pub(client, userdata, result):
    print('Published', result)
    pass

client = paho.Client('Pi')
client.on_publish = on_pub
client.username_pw_set(password = pwd, username = uname)
while True:
    [when some condition True]: #This condition isn't met very repeatedly very fast. Its a motion sensor that only sends a message if there hasn't been motion for a while, or if the motion reset counter has expired
        client.publish(topic = [topic], payload = [payload])
```

A simplified account of the micropython code on the ESP is as follows:

```
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient
import time
[Call function to connect to the WiFi function]

BROKER_IP = [broker_IP]
CLIENT_NAME = [client_name]
USER = [user]
PASSWORD = [password]
TOPIC = [topic]

x = [some_list]
def sub_cb(topic, msg):
    global x
    [clean the message string so its a list]
    [pass the cleaned list and x to a function]
    [reassign some variables so that the cleaned list becomes x for the time the message is recieved]

def connect_and_subscribe():
    global CLIENT_NAME, BROKER_IP, USER, PASSWORD, TOPIC
    client = MQTTClient(client_id=CLIENT_NAME,
                    server=BROKER_IP,
                    user=USER,
                    password=PASSWORD,
                    keepalive=60)
    client.set_callback(sub_cb)
    client.connect()
    client.subscribe(TOPIC)
    print('Connected to MQTT broker at: %s, subscribed to topic: %s' % (BROKER_IP, TOPIC))
    return(client)

client = connect_and_subscribe()

now = time.time()
while True:
    try: #In case broker has had to reboot, and check_masg fails, wait 60 secs and try again
        client.check_msg()
    except:
        time.sleep(60)
        client = connect_and_subscribe()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if time.time() - now > 80: #Ping every 80 secs to keep client alive (will drop client after 90secs (1.5 * keepalive value)
        client.ping()
        now = time.time()
```

The other thing i should note is that the function called in sub_cb can take 5 secs to run. I saw on the golang MQTT page that if the callback function invokes a long run-time, a separate go routine should be written for it. I saw nothing of the sort for the python documentation.

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to get rid of it? I don't want to just set `max_queued_messages 0` as I assume this will just store whatever is being stored until the system runs out memory and fails silently - but perhaps I have this wrong.

Comment: How long does it take?  Do you have debug messages from the ESP32 that show you it is still alive?  Is it, perhaps, going to sleep?

Comment: Edit the question to show the ESP32 code, QOS applies separately to both legs of the message. Also what is the message rate? The publishing code you have shown is a very tight and since it is QOS0 the broker is free to drop messages if the subscriber can not handle the rate

Comment: @TimRoberts The only way to debug i think is to have my computer connected to the serial port, which i have not done as the code runs for hours before failing. I note that the broker logs don't indicate any disconnect. If there is another way to check this, i can try. Otherwise i can leave the computer attached for a long period.

Comment: @hardillb I added the ESP code. As i note in the edits above the publishing rate isn't very fast. Its pushing messages for a motion sensor, and the code for that only runs if the there has not been motion for some time, or if the motion reset timer (which gets reset every time there is motion) has expired. This is on the order of minutes.

Comment: Change the ping to every 60 seconds, then there are not 20 seconds where the broker is waiting for the response. And yes you should never do long running tasks in the message callback no matter what language

Comment: @hardillb Thanks very much for this. Apologies for the slow reply. I made the changes you suggested. Also watched the messaging (through mosquitto_sub) and realized there was a condition that led to the message being spammed, while initiating a callback that triggered a function that took 5 seconds to run. I assume a queue got filled up with waiting function calls until no more messages could be sent. Notably after some time, that queue empties the messages start getting delivered again - very robust. If you want to jot down your comment as an answer, i'll happily accept. Thanks.